# JQuery use .on() with not selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using .on() function with this syntax:

```
$(".schemaTab").on("click", ".schema", function () {})
```

instead of `.live()` because I am adding `.schema` divs dynamically. Those divs have this code:

```
<div class="schema" id="SCH_16">
   <img src="Img/btnRemove.png" class="ikona SCH_Remove" alt="Smazat" title="Smazat">
</div>
```

But I need to exclude the img from click event of its parent div, so any idea how to do it?

I tried:

```
$(".schemaTab").not(".SCH_Remove").on("click", ".schema", function () {})
```

...but it didn't work and I don't know how to add the `.not()` inside the `.on()` code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

.not() won't work because `on` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object and uses the original selector to test whether the event should apply.

So I reckon selecting and then filtering in your case will do the trick.

API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

you could try this:

```
$(".schemaTab").on("click", ".schema", function (e) {

    if (!$(e.target).is(".schemaTab")) {
         // not stuff in here
    }

});
```

Comment: `this` will always be bound to the element that was checked; I think you mean `e.target`.

Answer (score 11):

You can actually use the `:not` selector with the `.on` method, like so.

This is a cleaner solution than filtering results per Tats_innit's answer.

```
$('.schemaTab').on('click', '.schema:not(.booga)', function(event) {
  // Fun happens here
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.0.

Comment: this seems to answer the question

Comment: @wazz That's a strange edit. I don't understand how "ran into a problem" is better than my previous "ran into this problem" text.

I guess it's a debate for the grammar stackoverflow

Comment: You're right. I thought it was a question, not a reply. Reverted. Grammatically, it should really be `that` ('this' led me to believe it was a question), but 'this' is better than 'a', for a reply.

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure the target matches:

```
$('.schemaTab').on('click', '.schema', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('.schema')) {
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of doing this is to handle events on elements not yet in the DOM, which includes your .sch_Remove.

```
$(".schemaTab").on("click", ".schema", function () {})
```

In order to prevent the parent click action from being triggered when that img is clicked, add the following (in addition to your function above).

```
$(".schemaTab").on("click", ".SCH_Remove", function () { return false; })
```

This will prevent the 'click' event from propagating to the parent and triggering its onclick method and prevent the default click behavior.

Comment: Just so you know though, since the img is currently the only thing in your div these two lines of code essentially cancel each other out. I assume you will be adding other things? otherwise you may need to rethink your approach