# Close a menu when user clicks anything except <li> and all its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

There have been many, many posts about this, but I can't get any of the methods to work. As a last resort, I tried listing out all of the list item's children using the .not() method (code below). But it still registers the click function.

```
$("body").not("li.settingsNav, li.settingsNav a, li.settingsNav i, 
               li.settingsNav span, li.settingsNav .module-dd, 
               li.settingsNav .module-dd-content, 
               li.settingsNav .module-dd .subnav-content, li.settingsNav span, 
               li.settingsNav div, li.settingsNav a, li.settingsNav ul, 
               li.settingsNav ul li")
         .on('click', function () {
               console.log('do this thing');
});
```

I want a click to trigger the action, except the  list item, and all divs/spans/etc. contained within it.

Thanks, and apologies for the repeat post.

Comment: You'll find the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335514/jquery-use-on-with-not-selector

Answer (score 2):

Easy thing to do is look at the target and see if it is your menu element. Give the parent UL a class.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.menu')) {
        $('#yourMenu').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('#yourMenuId').hide();
});

$('li.settingsNav').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I ended up finding [this article on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/test-if-element-inside-element/). It helped me test if the element clicked was inside another element. If the element clicked was inside the menu I wanted to leave open, then I stopped the event from propagating. If the element clicked was not inside .menu, which I wanted to leave open, then I closed the menu.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
     $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if ( $(e.target).parents(".menu").length == 1 ) { 
         e.stopPropagation();
    } else { 
        $('.menu').hide();
    }
     });
```